# Modify Mod_rewrite rule to add article title to URL

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have searched SO but all the examples here are not working for me.

```
I have a $_SESSION['title']; //Session variable contains title from calling page

$title = $_SESSION['title']; //local variable contains article title
```

Let's say the title of the article is news-of-the-day
How can I modify my rule to

```
http://www.newstoday.com/readnews/12/news-of-the-day

BTW http://www.newstoday.com/readnews/12 //this works

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^readnews/([0-9]+)$ readnews.php?news_art_id=$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^readnews/([0-9]+)(/(.*))?$ readnews.php?news_art_id=$1&other_params=$3
```

Added later: everything what goes after id will be in other_params GET param.

Comment: how can I use this in anchor link inside html?

Comment: both of your urls
http://www.newstoday.com/readnews/12/news-of-the-day
http://www.newstoday.com/readnews/12
will redirect to readnews.php script, where you can get "12"
from $_GET['news_art_id'] and "news-of-the-day" (for second case it's "") from $_GET['other_params'];

generation of such links from php:
$id = 0; // let's say this is your id
$title = $_SESSION['title'];
$link = 'http://www.newstoday.com/readnews/' . $id . '/' . $title;

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is incorrect. it should be:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^readnews/([0-9]+) readnews.php?news_art_id=$1
```

The $ indicates the end of the URL, but you want content after the id, you should remove it

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to make sure PHP is able to distinguish between the two URLs.

```
RewriteRule ^readnews/([0-9]+)(\/[a-z-]+)?$ readnews.php?news_art_id=$1&title=$2
```

This will make `$_POST['title']` contain `news-of-the-day` if the title is present in the URL - otherwise `$_POST['title']` will be empty. After this, you can simply check if it's set by PHP and redirect if not:

```
if (empty($_POST['title']))
  header("Location: /readnews/".$_POST['news_art_id']."/".$_SESSION['title']);
```

Comment: Going by your example...is it correct to have an anchor link like ths?.....<a href="/readnews/12/title">News healine</a>

Comment: Yes, both `/readnews/12` and `/readnews/12/title` should work. The former should redirect to the latter.